# LINQ Query matching two lists of items

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

my issue is that I have an attribute as 'attribute' coming in from entity framework.
So I retrieve this object which has a list of attribute tags, they are accessible via `attribute.AttributeTags`. Now I have a `asp:TextBox` where users can edit, remove and add new tags (comma separated). (On page load I am adding the attribute tags to this `TextBox`)

After a postback on the page I am returning the user input and splitting it into an array of strings and storing it in a variable called `AttributeTags`.

Now, I would like to add new tags that are not contained in the original `attributes` list coming from EF and would like to `remove` the ones that are contained in `attributes` but not found in the user input string array `AttributeTags`.

I am doing something like this:

```
        BusinessObjects.Attribute attribute = db.Attributes.FirstOrDefault(a => a.attribute_id == AttributeID);
        string[] AttributeTags = txtAttributeTags.Text.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (var item in AttributeTags)
        {
            if (!attribute.AttributeTags.Any(t => t.value == item))
            {
                AttributeTag tag = new AttributeTag { value = item, timestamp = DateTime.Now };
                attribute.AttributeTags.Add(tag);
            }
            else
            {
                AttributeTag tag = attribute.AttributeTags.FirstOrDefault(t => t.value == item);
            }
        }
```

But I'm sort of stuck here since i'm fairly new to LINQ and EF.

Comment: You should define class Attribute, AttributeTags, and you expected result, it's vague, where `val` comes from?

Comment: No I can't figure out how to `remove` the tags that were removed from the user input.

Comment: But your code does not show `remove`?

Comment: Please read my question... The remove part is what I don't know how to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two solution of this situations.

---

### First Solution

We can create an `ExcepWith` method that will allow us to remove all the items in a `ICollection<T>` that are already in give a `IEnumerable<T>`. The code for such method follows:

```
public static int ExceptWith<TItem>
(
    this ICollection<TItem> collection,
    IEnumerable<TItem> other
)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(collection, null))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");
    }
    else if (ReferenceEquals(other, null))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("other");
    }
    else
    {
        int count = 0;
        foreach (var item in other)
        {
            while (collection.Remove(item))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Now you have an `string[]` with the input of the user, that array is an `IEnumerable<string>` but not an an `ICollection<string>`... that is easily solved as follows:

Instead of this:

```
string[] AttributeTags =
    txtAttributeTags.Text.Split
    (
        new string[] { "," },
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
    );
```

You do this:

```
var AttributeTags =
    new List<string>
    (
        txtAttributeTags.Text.Split
        (
            new string[] { "," },
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
        )
    );
```

Or even this:

```
var AttributeTags =
    txtAttributeTags.Text.Split
    (
        new string[] { "," },
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
    ).ToList();
```

Now you can do this:

```
AttriuteTags.ExceptWith(existingTags);
```

Since the type of attribute.AttributeTag is not `IEnumerable<string>` you use Select:

```
AttriuteTags.ExceptWith(attribute.AttributeTag.Select(item => item.value));
```

And that leaves only the new tags in the list.

---

*Note*: this method depends on the implementation of Remove, if you need to do an special comparison, then you are out of luck with this method.

---

### Second Solution

There is another way. You can use the [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) from the `Enumerable` class.

```
string[] AttributeTags =
    txtAttributeTags.Text.Split
    (
        new string[] { "," },
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
    );
var newTags = AttributeTags.Except(existingTags);
```

Since the type of attribute.AttributeTag is not `IEnumerable<string>` you use Select:

```
string[] AttributeTags =
    txtAttributeTags.Text.Split
    (
        new string[] { "," },
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
    );
var newTags = AttributeTags.Except
(
    attribute.AttributeTag.Select(item => item.value)
);
```

And that puts in newTags, well, the new tags.

---

*Note*: If you need to do an special comparison, then you should use [the other overload of the method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx):

```
string[] AttributeTags =
    txtAttributeTags.Text.Split
    (
        new string[] { "," },
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
    );
var newTags = AttributeTags.Except(attribute.AttributeTag, equalityComparer);
```

Sadly the equalityComparer is an object of a class that implements IEqualityComparer, meaning that you can't use lambdas there. For that you can add this class:

```
public class CustomEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private Func<T, T, bool> _comparison;
    private Func<T, int> _getHashCode;

    public CustomEqualityComparer
    (
        Func<T, T, bool> comparison,
        Func<T, int> getHashCode
    )
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(comparison, null))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("comparison");
        }
        else if (ReferenceEquals(getHashCode, null))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("getHashCode");
        }
        else
        {
           _comparison = comparison;
           _getHashCode = getHashCode;
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return _comparison.Invoke(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return _getHashCode.Invoke(obj);
    }
}
```

And now invoke like this (for example):

```
string[] AttributeTags =
    txtAttributeTags.Text.Split
    (
        new string[] { "," },
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
    );
var newTags = AttributeTags.Except
(
    existingTags,
    new CustomEqualityComparer<string>
    (
        (a, b) => 1, //your custom comparison here
        str => str.GetHashCode()
    )
);
```

Since the type of attribute.AttributeTag is not `IEnumerable<string>` you use Select:

```
string[] AttributeTags =
    txtAttributeTags.Text.Split
    (
        new string[] { "," },
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
    );
var newTags = AttributeTags.Except
(
    attribute.AttributeTag.Select(item => item.value),
    new CustomEqualityComparer<string>
    (
        (a, b) => 1, //your custom comparison here
        str => str.GetHashCode()
    )
);
```

---

### Adding the new tags

Now that you have the new tags, let's say in `newTags`, you can iterate it to add the new tags:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
foreach (var item in newTags)
{
    AttributeTag tag = new AttributeTag { value = item, timestamp = now };
    attribute.AttributeTags.Add(tag);
}
```

---

### Comparing the Solutions

What's the difference of these methods?

- The first requires less memory
- The first requires to define a new method.
- The first doesn't allow for a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>`
- The second allows for deferred execution.
- The second uses (not needed) a helper class.

Answer (score 2):

A simplified example of how to do what you want.

```
var fromDB = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
var userInput = new List<string>() { "c", "d", "e", "f", "g" };
var result = fromDB.Join(userInput, x => x, y => y, (x, y) => x).Union(userInput);
```

Now all you have to do is replace the database contents with the results.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved very elegantly with an Iesi.Collections
There are several implementations of it, here is one: [Set Collections](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3190/Add-Support-for-quot-Set-quot-Collections-to-NET)

```
ListSet set1 = new ListSet(new [] {"1","2","8"});
ListSet set2 = new ListSet(new [] {"8","16","32"});
var union = set1 | set2;        // "1","2","8","16","32"
var intersect = set1 & set2;    // "8"
var diff = set1 ^ set2;         // "1","2","16","32"
var minus = set1 - set2;        // "1","2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that I tested. There are a lot of ways of saving in entity framework.

Note: please make sure not to modify/remove items while iterating a collection.

[image]

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAttributeTags" runat="server" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitButton" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" 
  Text="Submit" />

public const int AttributeID = 1;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    using (var db = new AttributeEntities())
    {
      var tags = db.AttributeTags
        .Where(a => a.attribute_id == AttributeID)
        .Select(a => a.value);

      txtAttributeTags.Text = string.Join(",", tags);
    }
  }
}

protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (var db = new AttributeEntities())
  {
    string[] newTags = txtAttributeTags.Text.Split(new[] {","}, 
      StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    var oldTags = db.AttributeTags.Where(t => t.attribute_id == AttributeID);

    foreach (var tag in oldTags.Where(o => !newTags.Contains(o.value)))
        db.AttributeTags.DeleteObject(tag);

    foreach (var tag in newTags.Where(n => !oldTags.Any(o => o.value == n)))
      db.AttributeTags.AddObject(new AttributeTag
      {
          attribute_id = AttributeID, value = tag, timestamp = DateTime.Now
      });

    db.SaveChanges();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

us the Remove method on the Attributes property of the db object then save changes

```
 db.Attributes.Remove( object );
```

Then Save changes to the db object.

This should work if I am assuming correctly that your db object is the connected object in the EF.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot do a full test, but something along these lines should do:

```
BusinessObjects.Attribute attribute = db.Attributes.FirstOrDefault(a => a.attribute_id == AttributeID);
string[] AttributeTags = txtAttributeTags.Text.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (var item in from a in AttributeTags
                     where attribute.AttributeTags.Any(t => t.value == a)
                     select new AttributeTag 
                     { 
                         value = item, 
                         timestamp = DateTime.Now 
                     })
    attribute.AttributeTags.Add(item);

foreach (var item in from a in attribute.AttributeTags
                     where AttributeTags.Any(t => t == a.value)
                     select a)
    attribute.AttributeTags.Remove(item);

db.SaveChanges();
```